# i want to make bell triangle with the assembly language emu8086

Tags: emu8086

i want to make bell triangle with the assembly language emu8086 like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_triangle

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Good luck in doing that!